# Ruby on Rails ActiveRecord Database Migration Failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, activerecord

I have a preexisting sqlserver database 'MyDatabase' populated with data.  Within this database I have two schemas, 'dbo' and 'Master'.

dbo is the default schema and contains tables:

- OWNER
- LOCATION

Master schema contains tables:

- BANK
- ZONE

Tables OWNER, LOCATION, BANK, and ZONE contain several attributes a piece.

I have initialized a RoR server and have verified that the appropriate gems are installed (activerecord, tiny_tds, activerecord-sqlserver-adapter), as well as that in database.yml the correct information is provided such that a connection can be established.  I ~am~ able to connect to the database. I am able to add and remove tables.

The unusual thing to me is that when I run `rake db:migrate`, only attributes from the dbo schema become automatically initialized in the schema.rb file of my RoR server:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20131014210258) do

  create_table "BANK", :id => false, :force => true do |t|
  end

  create_table "LOCATION", :id => false, :force => true do |t|
    t.string  "VarA",               :limit => 50
    t.string  "VarB",               :limit => 50
    t.decimal "VarC",               :precision => 28, :scale => 0
    t.integer "VarD"
    t.string  "VarE",               :limit => 500
  end

  create_table "OWNER", :id => false, :force => true do |t|
    t.string  "VarF",               :limit => 50
    t.string  "VarG",               :limit => 50
    t.string  "VarH",               :limit => 50
    t.string  "VarI",               :limit => 50
    t.string  "VarJ",               :limit => 50
  end

  create_table "ZONE", :id => false, :force => true do |t|
  end

end
```

Why is it that the attributes are not automatically populated for tables from my Master schema?  I have significantly reduced the scope of my database for this question...in actuality there are dozens of tables with dozens of attributes per, so doing the work manually is really not an option.

Is there a way to assign a specific schema(s) towards which ActiveRecord will default to search and generate attributes for?

Help! & Thank you in advance!

Comment: What do your migrations look like, and where from did you get/create them?  Maybe this posting will help creating a schema matching your preexisting DB: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19302002/generate-a-model-that-uses-pre-existing-data-from-database

Comment: Thats the thing... the schema I showed above was generated completely without a single model or migration defined in my rails app.  I made a new rails app, set up the database connection in database.yml, made sure I had the appropriate gems, and then ran 'rake db:migrate'.  Apparently activerecord searched the database and rendered this schema, except that it only automatically created fields for attributes of tables in the dbo schema of my database, whereas for tables in the Master schema, it did not automatically generate fields.  How can I fix this?

Comment: I think having multiple schemas in the same DB is what is confusing the adaptor.  I *think* the problem is probably in here https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter/blob/master/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver/schema_statements.rb (well the schema dumper part).  I am assuming the user you are connecting as has access to both `dbo` and `master`

Comment: Yes, the user has admin rights and has access to both the `dbo` and `Master` schema. I suppose we will condense the tables into a single schema, preferably `Master`, although technically the user's default schema is already `Master`, but obviously ActiveRecord is ignoring this somehow and still defaulting to `dbo`. I wish there were a way to indicate explicitly some schema for ActiveRecord to default to

Comment: Try asking metaskills, he is active on here, or perhaps submitting an issue on github about it.I've used the gem a bit, but only in porting away from Sql Server over to Postgres,but the majority of my stuff is all under 1 schema.