# How to Generate Rails App Models & Migrations for Legacy SQL Server Database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, activerecord

I'm having trouble creating models in my RoR application for preexisting tables in my sql server database.

In ruby console when I type: `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables`, the following is returned:
["Bank", "Owner", "Location", "Zone"].

The above is returned without any models or migrations having been created in the app.  So the next step is to create a model...

```
rails g model Bank
```

And edit the model:

```
class Bank < ActiveRecord::Base
    set_table_name = "Bank"
    set_primary_key "BankID"
end
```

And edit the migration:

```
class CreateBanks < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table "Master.Bank" do |t| // Because Bank is in the 'Master' schema, not the default 'dbo'

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

The edits to the model and migration file I have come to understand from my own research should allow me to successfully link a model in my app to a legacy database with table names that do not match Rails' conventions and in the appropriate schema.

However, after doing all this, the command `rake db:migrate` generates the error, "TinyTds::Error: There is already an object named 'Bank' in the database."

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If the tables already exist, you don't need to create them via  migration, Setting the table name in the Object should be all you need.   have you tried specifying "Master.Bank" as the table name, or mail sure the user you are accessing the server with has a default schema of "master", as opposed to "dbo"

Comment: Okay; When I delete the migration files for any preexisting tables, rake db:migrate passes. *yay*.  I'm still a bit confused, though - I was hoping that the answer to this question would somehow help me to figure out the answer to a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19370013/ruby-on-rails-activerecord-database-migration-failure.  Do I have to manually create the attributes in my model files for every attribute in the tables of my database? D:

Comment: i;ll look at your other question in a bit but look at the default schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are creating from a legacy DB, you don't know the migrations, as the tables already exist.  Rails *should* introspect the table and generate the correct fields.  Just make sure that the default schema for the user you are accessing the database with is the schema that owns the tables.

Comment: I think Rails-ActiveRecord has finally clicked for me.  Thank you for your help.